# How to determine twitter app by tweet?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I have twitter integrated to iPhone app by previous developer. Also have twitter consumer key & secret. I'm able to tweet by this app and see text like "via MyApp" below tweet. Now I need to change this twitter app settings, but don't know which twitter account this app belongs to. 
Is there any way to determine twitter account by tweet from some of it's apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the login details from the consumer key and secret. You will have to contact the previous developers to get the username and password for use on [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com).

Alternatively you can create your own new developer account.

Comment: Yes, but they don't remember account username too). If I could find out login, they will give me password for that account.

Comment: Well they need to use the "forgot username/password" feature. There's not really anything we can do to help with this issue.

Comment: Here problem is they have many twitter accounts (I suppose) that they use for twitter integration in iPhone apps they develop. Option to create new developer account is also not suitable becuase I need to be sure that previous versions of app will work after I change twitter app settings.